# ReactJS: How can I change dynamically inserted Component's data

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change children Component to another component by using state. This injects new Component correctly, however, if I want to change its props dynamically, nothing is changing. `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't triggered.

In my scenario, I'll have many components like `TestComponent` (nearly 20-30 components) and they all have different HTML layout (also they have sub components, too). I switch between those components by selecting some value from some list.

Loading all those components initially doesn't seem a good idea I think. On the other hand, I haven't found anything about injecting a Component inside main Component dynamically.

Here is a very basic example of what I want to achieve. When clicking on the button, I insert `TestComponent` inside `App`. After that, on every one second, I increment a state value which I try to bind `TestComponent` but, the component value is not updating.

If I use commented snippet inside `setInterval` function instead of uncommented, it works but I have to write 20-30 switch case for finding the right component in my real code (which I also wrote when selecting a value from list) so, I want to avoid using that. Also, I'm not sure about the performance.

So, is this the correct approach, if so, how can I solve this problem? If it is wrong, what else can I try?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      component: <p>Initial div</p>,
      componentData: 0
    };
    
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }
  
  onClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      component: <TestComponent currentValue={this.state.componentData} />
    });
    
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        componentData: this.state.componentData + 1
      })
      
      // This will update TestComponent if used instead of above
      /*this.setState({
        componentData: this.state.componentData + 1,
        component: <TestComponent currentValue={this.state.componentData} />
      });*/
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Click the button</h4>
        <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Change Component</button>
        {this.state.component}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      currentValue: this.props.currentValue
    };
  }
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: nextProps.currentValue
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Current value: {this.state.currentValue}</p>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  ,document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically render the child components you can use React.createElement method in parent, which results in invoking different components, this can be used as, below is sample code, hope it helps.

```
getChildComponent = (childComponentName) => {
        const childComponents = {
                TestComponent1,
                TestComponent2,
                TestComponent3,
                TestComponent4
            },
            componentProps = Object.assign({}, this.props,this.state, {
                styles: undefined
            });
        if (childComponents[childComponentName]) {
            return React.createElement(
                                        childComponents[childComponentName], 
                                        componentProps);
        }
        return null;
    }

render(){
    this.getChildComponents(this.state.childComponentName);
}
```

Here in the render function, pass the component name, and child will render dynalicaaly. Other way of doing this can be, make childComponents object as array , look below fora sample

```
const childComponents = [
                    TestComponent1,
                    TestComponent2,
                    TestComponent3,
                    TestComponent4
                ]
```

> Note: You have to import all child components here in parent, these
>   are not strings.

Comment: This is basically what I do now (when setting state `component` value to `TestComponent` ; `React.createElement` is non-JSX version of what I am doing). I have problems on updating dynamically generated components' data.

Comment: Actually, having a function which takes a state parameter in `render` does the trick. I think the magic is always to create component inside `render`. Your example doesn't contain any state parameter pass to child component props but I get the idea.

Comment: You can pass state parameters to child using using the below one componentProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, this.state, {
                styles: undefined
            });

Answer (score 1):

That's because as Facebook mentions in their React documentation.

> When you call `setState()`, React merges the object you provide into the current state.
>
> **The merging is shallow**
>
> For further information [read the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

So for this case the only modified value will be  `componentData` and `component` won't trigger any updates

## Solution

A better case to solve this issue is using **[Higher-Order components (HOC)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)** so the `App` component doesn't care which component you are trying to render instead It just receives a component as a prop so you can pass props to this component base on the `App` state.

Also, you don't need a state in `TestComponent` since you get the value as a prop and it's handled by `App`.

I also added a condition to prevent adding multiples `setInterval`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  interval;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      componentData: 0
    };

    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this);
  }
  
  onClickHandler = () => {
    if (!this.interval) {
      this.setState({
        componentData: this.state.componentData + 1
      });

      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          componentData: this.state.componentData + 1
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    let Timer = this.props.timer;

    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Click the button</h4>
        <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Change Component</button>
        {!this.state.componentData ? <p>Initial div</p> : <Timer currentValue={this.state.componentData} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { currentValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <p>Current value: {currentValue}</p>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App timer={TestComponent} /> ,document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: So, if I assing a state value into a state key like `this.state = { value: this.state.newValue, newValue: 1 };` (`value` is undefined at first, no problem) and change state key with `this.setState({ newValue: 2 });`, it won't change `state.value`. Am I correct?

Comment: @alalp you can't set a value of an undefined object, you will an error if you do this, you are trying to set `value` of a yet undefined `this.state.newValue `

Comment: My bad, sorry. Trying to shorten the comment. State initialization is: `this.state = { newValue: 1, value: 0 };`. Later, `this.setState({ value: this.state.newValue} );`. And finally `this.setState({ newValue: 2 });`. This won't change `state.value` to 2, right?

Comment: definitely not! `this.setState({ value: this.state.newValue} );` It's an assignment not a reference